# Adding a custom header/cookie to a Bad Request (400) ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, cookies, http-headers

I'm trying to manipulate the header in ASP.Net core for 400 errors.

My specific scenario is adding a cookie when a user successfully generates and downloads a report.  I have the cookies working via a Middleware.

I'm searching for a way to manipulate the Response for `ModelState` errors or `BadRequestObjectResult` globally.  The Middleware doesn't appear to have access to the ModelState errors.

Below is the middleware that I have currently

````cs
   public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            if (TryGetReportMonitorParam(context, out var token))
            {
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                {
                    MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, CookieDurationSeconds / 60, CookieDurationSeconds % 60), // Expires in 5 minutes
                    Secure = true, // Only transmit cookie over HTTPS //this is just a timestamp for a report
                    HttpOnly = false // Client-side can read cookie
                };

                Task OnResponseStarting()
                {
                    var cookieValue = context.Response.StatusCode.ToString("d3");
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append(token, cookieValue, cookieOptions); // Add cookie to the response
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                context.Response.OnStarting(OnResponseStarting);
            }
            await next(context); // Go on and do the requested stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If there is a report monitor parameter in the request, return it
        /// Return true if found
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="commit"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool TryGetReportMonitorParam(HttpContext context, out string token)
        {
            if (context.Request.Query.TryGetValue(UrlParameterName, out var values))
            {
                var stringValues = (string[])values;
                if (stringValues != null && stringValues.Length > 0)
                {
                    token = stringValues[0];
                    return true;
                }
            }
            token = null;
            return false;
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

For the long answer, here is the code.   You would also need to tell the framework to use the filter.

```cs
 public class ReportMonitorMiddlewareOptions
    {
        public int CookieDurationSeconds { get; set; }
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportMonitorFilter : IAlwaysRunResultFilter
    {
        private readonly ReportMonitorMiddlewareOptions _options;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ReportMonitor"></param>
        public ReportMonitorFilter(IOptions<ReportMonitorMiddlewareOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        private string UrlParameterName => _options.ParameterName ?? "respm";

        private int CookieDurationSeconds
        {
            get
            {
                if (_options.CookieDurationSeconds <= 0)
                {
                    return 300; // 5 minutes
                }
                return _options.CookieDurationSeconds;
            }
        }

        private bool TryGetReportMonitorParam(HttpRequest request, out string token)
        {
            if (request.Query.TryGetValue(UrlParameterName, out var values))
            {
                var stringValues = (string[])values;
                if (stringValues != null && stringValues.Length > 0)
                {
                    token = stringValues[0];
                    return true;
                }
            }
            token = null;
            return false;
        }

        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
        }

        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (TryGetReportMonitorParam(context.HttpContext.Request, out var token))
            {
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                {
                    MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, CookieDurationSeconds / 60, CookieDurationSeconds % 60),
                    Secure = true, // Only transmit cookie over HTTPS //this is just a timestamp for a report
                    HttpOnly = false // Client-side can read cookie
                };

                string cookieValue;
                if (context.Result is FileResult)
                {
                    cookieValue = "200";
                }
                else if (context.Result is BadRequestObjectResult badResult)
                {
                    if (badResult.Value is ValidationProblemDetails details && details?.Errors.Keys.Count > 0)
                    { 
                        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(details.Errors);
                        cookieValue = $"400:{jsonString}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookieValue = $"400";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cookieValue = "999";
                }
                
                context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(token, cookieValue, cookieOptions); // Add cookie to the response
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fascinating, I never heard about this filter (`IAlwaysRunResultFilter`) until now, even though I've been working with ASP.NET Core for 2 years. So definitely +1 for the curiosity factor. :) Btw, I tried to reproduce the issue yesterday, but I was able to add a header even when the request bounced with a validation error. But maybe I misunderstood the question.